# ng-repeat does not update view after ajax request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my controller

```
app.controller('topicsController', ['API','$scope', function(API,$scope){
  $scope.$on('loadTopics',function(){
    API.topics.query(function(data){ 
       $scope.topics=data;
       console.log('topics loaded'); 
    });
 });
}]);
```

HTML

```
    <div class="right_side" >
         <aside class="user_tags" ng-controller="topicsController">
         <h4>Actual topics</h4>
         <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="topic in topics" ><a ui-sref="topicpage({tag:topic.tag})">{{topic.tag}}</a></li>
         </ul>
        </aside>
    </div>
```

The problem is that view updating only on page reload, but if ajax request called on page ( via button ex.), the view does not update.
Searched a lot, tried $timeout and $apply, both haven't helped.

Comment: When do you broadcast `loadTopics`? Since you are using $on, only when you do a $broadcast or $emit will the query get triggered

Comment: Yes, show us the full code. When is `$rootScope.$broadcast('loadTopics');` triggered?

Comment: Don't think about emit/broadcast/on, problem isn't here. Even if AJAX is called with function, variable `$scope.topics` updates, it can be seen with `alert()`, but view is not.

Comment: @Satpal it doesn't helped, wrote about it

Comment: How is the API service implemented?  Does it use $http or something else?

Comment: You wrote "Even if AJAX is called with function" - I have a little Plunker here doing that: http://plnkr.co/edit/Tgb9thkeEdZaDM9tfeKj?p=preview Updating seems to work...

Comment: @timtos Don't compare `push()`, and `$http` request. I know that push works.

Comment: Ok. But then it has something to do with $http. Wrong return value of the function? Problem with a promise? Check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http - here is an example at the bottom. Success.